# pandas to_csv argument float_format to a percentage

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point, export-to-csv

I am trying to output a pandas dataframe but I want it to output the floats as a percentage. I've done a fair amount of searching on this, and I can make them display as floats in the output exactly like I want using

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2%}'.format
```

but what I want is to do the exact same thing except when I export to a .csv using the `.to_csv` method.

Sample code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Index': ['One', 'Two'], 'col1': [.1, .2], 'col2': [.3, .4], 'col3': [1, 7]})
df2.set_index('Index')
```

df:

```
    col1    col2    col3
Index           
One 0.1     0.3     1
Two 0.2     0.4     7
```

col1 and col2 are float64 and col3 is an integer

I want to use the following (or something like it of course):

```
dfs.to_csv("filelocation and name.csv", float_format = '{:.2%}'.format)
```

to output to a .csv that would look like:

```
    col1    col2    col3
Index           
One 10%     30%     1
Two 20%     40%     7
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've hit errors from "TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray._ _ format _ _" to "KeyError: '%'" and a few in between.

Comment: It seems like one clear method of doing this would be to do a simple mapping  on the two columns before exporting, but I would really like to be able to use the float_format tag in the to_csv method.  `df['col1'] = df['col1'].map('${:,.2%}'.format)` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to `float_format` to format the output in the csv file, but that is just a `string`, that means you can format the columns, but not operate on them. For example

```
with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    df2.to_csv(f, index = False, header = True, float_format = '%.2f%%')
```

will create this output

```
Index,col1,col2,col3
One,0.10%,0.30%,1
Two,0.20%,0.40%,7
```

If you want to change the values I suggest you to update the dataframe before outputting

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'Index': ['One', 'Two'], 'col1': [.1, .2], 'col2': [.3, .4], 'col3': [1, 7]})
df2.set_index('Index')

df2['col1'] *= 100
df2['col2'] *= 100

with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    df2.to_csv(f, index = False, header = True, float_format = '%.2f%%')
```

Comment: That makes it a lot clearer what the actual purpose is for the `float_format` tag. If I use the method you suggested, that would save the value as a string, correct? i.e. "10%"

Comment: @JustinG Yes, it will save it as a string, e.g. `10.00%`, if you want `10%` you can try `'%.0f%%'`